# Car shifts hard when warm

Tags: toyota, transmission

My car, 2003 Toyota Camry shifts hard when warm. Fliud level is normal, mileage is 100k. I cannot spend too much time on it, just want to try some inexspensive tests, to understand what could be the problem. If you have any ideas on what it can be, please let me know.

2.4 liters 4-cylinder engine, automatic transmission.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the transmission oil and filter. Also, take a look and see if the linkage to the transmission is bent anywhere.